# How to calculate coordinates of point P on an ellipse that has a tangent line at 45 degrees

Tags: trigonometry

I have the equation of an ellipse: $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}=1$

In the upper left quadrant, how do I find the coordinates of tangent point P whose tangent line is at an angle of 45 degrees with the x-axis (slope of 1)?

I haven't done this kind of math in nearly a decade, so I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this without derivative:

Let the tangent line be $y=x+c$. Substitute into equation of the ellipse: $$\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{(x+c)^2}{9}=1$$ $$\implies13x^2+8cx+(4c^2-36)=0\tag{*}$$

Since the tangent touches the ellipse (at exactly one point), the discriminant of $(*)$ has to be zero: $$\Delta=-144(c^2-13)=0\implies c^2=13\implies c=\pm\sqrt{13}.$$ $c=\sqrt{13}$ is obvious.

Back to $(*)$, $13x^2+8\sqrt{13}x+(4\sqrt{13}^2-36)=0\implies x=\dfrac{-4}{\sqrt{13}}$, a repeated root.

Comment: this was the easiest method for me to understand. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, so I went through this and ran into trouble when it came to plugging C into the (*) equation. How did you go from 13x^2 + 8*(13^0.5)*x + (4 * 13 - 36) = 0 to x = -4/(13^.5)?

Comment: @Sean $13x^2+8\sqrt{13}x+(4\sqrt{13}^2-36)=13x^2+8\sqrt{13}x+16=13(x+\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{13}})^2=0$ by completing square.

Answer (score 0):

Find the derivative:

$$\frac{x}{2}+\frac{2yy'}{9}=0 \qquad \qquad(1)$$

You know that at some point on the ellipse $(x_1,y_1)$ the slope of the tangent is $y_1'=\tan 45^o = 1$

If you replace $x_1,y_1$ and $y_1'$ into the equation of ellipse and (1), you get the followwing system of two equations and two variables:

$$\frac{x_1^2}{4}+\frac{y_1^2}{9}=1 $$

$$\frac{x_1}{2}+\frac{2y_1}{9}=0$$

You can easily solve this system by eliminating one variable from the second equation and replacing it into the first. You'll get a quadratic equation with two solutions. Just pick the one from the second quadrant $(x_1\lt0)$

Answer (score -1):

The ellipse has the parametric equation $x=2\cos t, y=3\sin t$ (with $t\in[0,2\pi])$. The tangent vector at $t$ is $(-2\sin t,3\cos t)$. It makes an angle $45^\circ$ with the horizontal if $-2\sin t=3\cos t$, that is $\tan t=-\frac{3}{2}$. Given that you want the point to the in the upper left quadrant, that means $t=\pi-\arctan\frac32$. Then the point on the ellipse has coordinates

$$x=2\cos(\pi-\arctan\frac32)=-2\cos\arctan\frac32$$
$$y=3\sin(\pi-\arctan\frac32)=3\sin\arctan\frac32$$

Let $\alpha=\arctan\frac32\in]0,\pi/2[$ (so that $\cos\alpha$ and $\sin\alpha$ are both positive). From $\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha=1$, you get $1+\tan^2\alpha=\dfrac1{\cos^2\alpha}$ then

$$\cos\alpha=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\alpha}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}$$
$$\sin\alpha=\tan\alpha\cos\alpha=\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}}$$

Hence $x=-\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{13}}$ and $y=\dfrac{9}{\sqrt{13}}$.